# How do I unlock the Lost Witch raiment?

Tags: soul-sacrifice

The condition is "defeat Illecebra 3 times", I see that I've defeated Illecebra twice, but I've tried to defeat all Illecebras in Beginning of the End and Fading Humanity to no avail.

Which Illecebra should I defeat?

This is for Soul Sacrifice Delta, but I can't make a new tag in mobile, so I use the standard Soul Sacrifice tag

Comment: Illecebra in story mode does not count on killing, you must fight one on pact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to defeat the double Illecebra Archfiends found in The Memories Remain Revised, where you can Sacrifice her and obtain Illecebra SE/LE, instead of her in Beginning of the End where you'll get Lost Witch soul.